# Difference Latches and Flip-Flops

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-engineering

I am trying to understand the difference between Latches and Flip-Flops, as an example: RS-Latch and RS-Flip-Flop. In my lecture script the only difference is that latches are level triggered and Flip-Flops are edge triggered, so far now problem.

In one task we had to build an RS-Flip-Flop with Nor gates, could someone give me an example of it? Because in the Solutions there is a picture of an RS-Latch (the one you can see on wikipedia), but latches are edge-triggered, so we can't build an Flip-Flop by using just two nor gates, can we?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're inconsistent, you start of by correctly stating that latches are level triggered and flip-flops are edge triggered. But your second paragraph you incorrectly say that latches are edge triggered. If you know how to make a latch then you can make a flipflop from two latches. Connect the outputs of the first latch to the inputs of the second. Connect the clock to the enable of the second latch and the inverse of the clock to the enable of the first latch,

Answer (score 1):

The main difference latches and flip-flops are that former are level triggered that is once the latch is enabled the change in inputs can show change in output after latch is disabled the values are fixed, the latches are edge triggered that is when the clock pulse start rising,or falling the output across the latch changes if there is change in input.

For making a SR flip flop you should first make the table and draw the K map of the outputs and then you can use NOR gates to solve the problem.
 [image: vjh]

- [Latches and Flip-Flops](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~ehwang/courses/cs120b/flipflops.pdf)